# Moving Text to Downward using matchedGeometryEffect

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

There are two `Text()` in the code. First one is blue and other is red. I just want to downward the animation from **first Text()** to **second Text()**. Which is now going reverse way!

I tried changing the isSource: true/false but no luck!

[image]

Here is the code:

```
struct AnimDown: View {
    
    @State private var textAnim = "2344"
    @State private var counter = 0
    @Namespace private var ns1

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            
            Text(textAnim)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: counter, in: ns1, isSource: true)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .animation(.easeInOut, value: counter)
          
            Text(textAnim)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: counter, in: ns1, isSource: false)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .animation(.easeInOut, value: counter)
          
            
            Button("Move Down") {
                textAnim = String("\(Int.random(in: 1..<99))")
                counter += 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the blue text? It is unclear what the desired effect is.

Comment: @Sweeper There are two `Text()`  in the code. First one is blue and other is red. I just want to downward the animation from **first Text()** to **second Text()**. Which is now going reverse way!

Answer (score 1):

You can make your code *kind of* work by adding an `id` modifier to the “blue” `Text`, and changing the `id` each time you change the text:

```
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(textAnim)
                .id(counter) // ‼️ ADD THIS
                .matchedGeometryEffect(
                    id: counter,
                    in: ns1,
                    isSource: false
                )
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
          
            Text(textAnim)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(
                    id: counter,
                    in: ns1,
                    isSource: true
                )
                .foregroundColor(.red)
            
            Button("Move Down") {
                textAnim = String("\(Int.random(in: 1..<99))")
                counter += 1
            }
        }
        .animation(.easeInOut, value: counter)
    }
```

Then it looks like this:

[image]

But as you can see from the animation, it's not correct if you tap the button again before the first animation is finished.

Here's a better solution:

```
struct BetterView: View {
    @State private var textAnim = "2344"
    @State private var matched = true
    @Namespace private var ns1

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(textAnim)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(
                    id: matched ? "text" : "temp",
                    in: ns1,
                    isSource: !matched
                )
                .foregroundColor(.blue)

            Text(textAnim)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(
                    id: "text",
                    in: ns1,
                    isSource: true
                )
                .foregroundColor(.red)

            Button("Move Down") {
                withAnimation(nil) {
                    textAnim = String("\(Int.random(in: 1..<99))")
                    matched = false
                }
                withAnimation {
                    matched = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

The trick here is that I don't use an `animation` modifier to implicitly animate the changes. Instead:

- When I change `textAnim`, I set the blue `Text` to have a different `matchedGeometryEffect` identifier than the red `Text`, and make the blue `Text` its own source, and I do that with animation disabled. So the blue `Text` seems to appear in its natural position instantly.
- Then, with an explicit animation, I change the blue `Text` to have the same `matchedGeometryEffect` identifier as the red `Text`, and make the blue `Text` **not** be a source. So the blue `Text` animates to the red `Text`'s position.

Answer (score 0):

The `View` which has `isSource: false` is moving from its initial location to the position identified by the view with `isSource: true`.

However, since both views are being shown at the same time, it seems you only get some movement if the source view appears before the non-source view in the layout. So:

- When the source is first, non-source is second, the numbers are seen to move up. When the numbers reach their target position, they are seen as red, because this view appears later in the layout.
- When the non-source is first and the source is second, the initial position of the non-source view is already set to the source view. In this case, there is no movement. And since the source appears later, this is the one on top, so the numbers are blue.

To force the numbers to go down, the floating (non-source) view can be put in an overlay instead. By using `alignment: top`, it starts at the top of the `VStack` frame. If some top padding is added to the `VStack` too, the non-source view will move down from the top of the `VStack` to the position of the source view:

```swift
VStack(spacing: 20) {

    Text(textAnim)
        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: counter, in: ns1, isSource: true)
        .foregroundColor(.blue)
        .animation(.easeInOut, value: counter)

    Button("Move Down") {
        textAnim = String("\(Int.random(in: 1..<99))")
        counter += 1
    }
}
.padding(.top, 50)
.overlay(alignment: .top) {
    Text(textAnim)
        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: counter, in: ns1, isSource: false)
        .foregroundColor(.red)
        .animation(.easeInOut, value: counter)
}
```

[image: Animation]