# Text animation from smaller to bigger size in swiftUI

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

Animation between two `Text()` works fine for same text size. From big text to small text size also works with `.minimumScaleFactor(0.1)`.

But how can I animate **from smaller to Bigger text size**?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
struct AnimView: View {
    @State private var textAnim = "23"
    @State private var matched = true
    @Namespace private var ns1

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
              
            Text(textAnim)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: matched ? "text" : "temp",in: ns1,isSource: !matched)
                .font(.system(size: 16))
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.1)
            
            Spacer()
                .frame(height: 50)
            
            Text(textAnim)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "text", in: ns1, isSource: true)
                .font(.system(size: 36))
                .foregroundColor(.red)

            
            Button("Move Down") {
                withAnimation(nil) {
                    textAnim = String("\(Int.random(in: 1..<99))")
                    matched = false
                }
                withAnimation {
                    matched = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have noticed that errors were appearing in the console for your example:

> Multiple inserted views in matched geometry group Pair<String, ID>(first: "text", second: SwiftUI.Namespace.ID(id: 134)) have `isSource: true`, results are undefined.

I would suggest a different approach:

- Use hidden placeholders for the two text positions.
- The floating view is shown in an overlay (see also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78188196/20386264) to your previous question).

Since it is always the same view that is visible, the transition from small to big is seamless. Also, it always has the same color.

```swift
struct AnimView: View {
    @State private var textAnim = "23"
    @State private var isBig = true
    @Namespace private var ns1

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(textAnim)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "top", in: ns1, isSource: true)
                .font(.system(size: 16))
                .hidden()

            Spacer()
                .frame(height: 50)

            Text(textAnim)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "bottom", in: ns1, isSource: true)
                .font(.system(size: 36))
                .hidden()

            Button("Move Down") {
                textAnim = String("\(Int.random(in: 1..<99))")
                isBig = false
                withAnimation {
                    isBig = true
                }
            }
        }
        .overlay {
            Text(textAnim)
                .font(.system(size: 36))
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.1)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: isBig ? "bottom" : "top", in: ns1, isSource: false)
                .foregroundStyle(.red)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Animation]

Answer (score -1):

```
struct AnimView: View {
@State private var textAnim = "23"
@State private var matched = true
@Namespace private var ns1

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        if matched {
            Text(textAnim)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: matched ? "text" : "temp", in: ns1, isSource: !matched)
                .font(.system(size: 16))
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.1)
                .transition(.opacity) // Add transition for smoother animation
        } else {
            Text(textAnim)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "text", in: ns1, isSource: true)
                .font(.system(size: 36))
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .transition(.opacity) // Add transition for smoother animation
        }
        
        Spacer()
            .frame(height: 50)
        
        Button("Move Down") {
            withAnimation {
                textAnim = String("\(Int.random(in: 1..<99))")
                matched.toggle() // Toggle matched state directly for better animation
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

**See if this works**

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**